# Logical processing of CTE recursive query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

This query returns all days between date range defined with variables and result set is 31 distinct values. But, recursive CTE works in such a way that first query executed only once, and second query works on result set created before. So, it seems that there will be duplicates, but it returned distinct result set. Whether CTE apply DISTINCT clause internally or is it something else? How I get DISTINCT values?

```
DECLARE 
    @DateFrom DATE = '20130101' ,
    @DateTo DATE = '20130131'

WITH Days
AS ( SELECT CAST(@DateFrom AS DATETIME) AS dt
     UNION ALL
     SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, dt)
     FROM Days s
     WHERE DATEADD(dd, 1, dt) <= CAST(@DateTo AS DATETIME)
   )

SELECT dt 
FROM Days
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you think there will be duplicates

Comment: Because anchor element was executed only once, and second select in CTE works on previous result set. So in first step, in Days CTE will be only one row '20120101'. Second step will add to that result one more row '20120102'. But, in third iteration, CTE Days have two rows, and with UNION ALL add to that two rows new two rows, incremented with 1. So there will be duplicates, in my opinion.

Comment: No, in third iteration, it only considers the rows that were added in the second iteration. There's only one row in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time a CTE recurses, it uses the rows produced by the previous recursion (or the initial set of rows if this is the first time it recurses).

So, for your query, the first run produces a single row - `'20130101'` converted to a datetime.

For the first recursive step, we take all the rows produced by the last recursion or initial set (`'20130101'`) and use it to produce one new row, which contains `'20130102'`.

For the next recursive step, we take all rows produced by the last recursion (`'20130102'`) and use it to produce one new row (`'20130103'`)

For the next recursive step, we take all rows produced by the last recursion (`'20130103'`) and use it to produce one new row (`'20130104'`)

I don't see anywhere where duplicates are going to arise.

Read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx):

> The semantics of the recursive execution is as follows:
>
> 1. Split the CTE expression into anchor and recursive members.
> 2. Run the anchor member(s) creating the first invocation or base result set (`T0`).
> 3. Run the recursive member(s) with `Ti` as an input and `Ti+1` as an output.
> 4. Repeat step 3 until an empty set is returned.
> 5. Return the result set. This is a `UNION ALL` of `T0` to `Tn`.

Comment: I am confusing a bit about next: in one book I read that in each iteration, reference to the CTE name from the recursive member represents the previous result set. So whether is that result set combination of all previous generated rows, or just last generated row?

Comment: @veljasije - just the set generated by the previous recursion. (Step 3 in the quoted bit of MSDN). The actual `UNION` of these sets doesn't occur until step 5.

Comment: You gave me real explanation. I thought before that `UNION ALL` executes in each iteration and that was source of my confusion.